# How to create multiple implementations of UserDetailsService in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I want to customize login API in spring boot. For a single kind of user, I created a implementation of UserDetailsService and it worked perfectly fine. Now, I want to create 3 different kinds of users, i.e., 3 different authorities. I don't think a single implementation can help me here. If I create 3 different implementations, and try using @Qualifier, how do I call a specific implementation ?
Any sort of help is appreciated! Below is the code for Login Endpoint of single kind Of user.

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

@Value("${jwt.expires_in}")
private int EXPIRES_IN;

@Autowired
AuthenticationManager authManager;

@Autowired
TokenHelper tokenHelper;

@Autowired
ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@Autowired
PrincipalRepository principalRepository;

private boolean isAuthenticated(Authentication authentication) {
    return authentication != null && !(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) && authentication.isAuthenticated();
}

@PostMapping("/principal")
public ResponseEntity<Object[]> loginPrincipal(@RequestParam(name ="username") String username,
                                    @RequestParam(name ="password") String password){

    logger.info("In login api");
    if(StringUtils.isEmpty(username) || StringUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        logger.error("Invalid Request!");
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().header("reason", "bad request").body(null);
    }
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authReq = 
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
    Authentication authentication = authManager.authenticate(authReq);
    boolean isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated(authentication);
    if (!isAuthenticated) {
        logger.error("Not authenticated");
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(null);
    }

    Principal principal = null;
    try {
        principal = principalRepository.findByUserName(username);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        logger.error("Couldn't retrieve user");
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().header("reason", "username not found").body(null);
    }

    String jwt = tokenHelper.generateToken( username );
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    UserTokenState userTokenState = new UserTokenState(jwt, EXPIRES_IN);

    return ResponseEntity.accepted().body(new Object[] {userTokenState, principal.getPrincipalID()});
}
```

Below is the code for UserDetailsService Implementation:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private PrincipalRepository principalRepository;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("Loading user from db");
    Principal principal = principalRepository.findByUserName(username);

    if( principal == null){
        System.out.println("User not found");
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user found. Username tried: " + username);
    }

    Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
    grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_PRINCIPAL"));
    System.out.println("All done");
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(principal.getUserName(), principal.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
}
```

}

Here, I am fetching a principal from db, because this implementation is principal-specific. I wanna create similar implementations for Student and Teacher and use them accordingly.

Comment: Why should the user differ? Just assign a different role/authority to them. The user account can still be the same, you are making things overly complex imho. Also with your current solution you are working around Spring Security (as that should be the thing handling the login, not your controller).

Comment: @M.Deinum Users with different authorities, have lot of different functionalities and attributes. I thought creating separate tables in db/ creating different users will make it easier. Do you still recommend to create a single user ? And I have to work around Spring Security to implement JWT. So, for JWT, implementation of UserDetailsService is required too.

Comment: The entities in your system don't necessarily need to be the user accounts, you can treat those as different concerns and responsibilities of your application. Also no you don't need to work around Spring Security (nor should you) for JTW. You could use the default Spring user details service provide a query with a union over 3 tables and return the common parts as the user (username, password, enabled etc.). You can then simply use the default components of Spring Security.

Comment: With this approach can I let users from different authorities share same username?

Comment: Why would the username need to be the same ? imho this would only lead to issues.

Answer (score 0):

You **don't need** to create **more than one** implementation for `UserDetailsService`. `Student`, `Teacher` are also users, only one thing will differ these users is *"authorities"*(role & authorities) in the application if we look at from general view. **Spring Security** firstly checks "*username*" and "*password*" for **authentication** and after successful authentication, it checks "*authorities*" for **authorization** process in order to allow to use resources(methods, and etc) according to the business logic of the application.

Comment: With this approach can I let users from different authorities share same username?

Comment: If username presents in authentication the answer is NO. Username must be unique.  Username is part of authentication, "authorities" is part of authorization.               
NOTE: By default username and password are required by Spring Security for authentication purpose(to identify the user whom is authenticated or not). You can add more fields for authentication for ex: (student-email, student-number, password and etc).

Comment: Thanks for the information :) I am actually bounded to let users with different authorities share the same username. So, I have actually figured out a way for doing this. If principal tries to login I append a character "p", for student, I append "s" and for teacher "t", before their respective usernames. This happens in login API. I pass this modified username in UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken() object and can easily perform operations in UserDetailsService Implementation by extracting this first character and searching in required db accordingly.

Comment: You must have unique information in order to identify user, this can be username, email, or any information which only one user has that information(unique for one user).                                                                                                                             Have you checked what happens if multiple students or teachers or principals attempt to login ? They will have the same username for authentication (for ex: pstudent for all students)?